# Is there a JSON listing somewhere of all the Node.js version numbers?

Tags: node.js, json, api

I am after all the full Node.js version numbers for some testing software, however I can't seem to find any JSON listings. The closest I found was https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/Release/master/schedule.json however that is just major versions, not every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON list of release downloads is available from the nodejs.org site

https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.json

It's an array of objects:

```
{
  "version":"v16.4.0",
  "date":"2021-06-23",
  "files":["aix-ppc64","headers","linux-arm64","linux-armv7l","linux-ppc64le","linux-s390x","linux-x64","osx-arm64-tar","osx-x64-pkg","osx-x64-tar","src","win-x64-7z","win-x64-exe","win-x64-msi","win-x64-zip","win-x86-7z","win-x86-exe","win-x86-msi","win-x86-zip"],
  "npm":"7.18.1",
  "v8":"9.1.269.36",
  "uv":"1.41.0",
  "zlib":"1.2.11",
  "openssl":"1.1.1k+quic",
  "modules":"93",
  "lts":false,
  "security":false
}
```

A command to pull specific versions, dates and security status:

```
curl -sf https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.json \
 | jq -r '
    .[]
    | select(.version|match("^v1[68]"))
    | "\(.date) \(.version) \(.security // "")"
   '
```

```
2022-05-17 v18.2.0 
2022-05-03 v18.1.0 
2022-04-18 v18.0.0 
2022-04-26 v16.15.0 
2022-03-17 v16.14.2 true
2022-03-16 v16.14.1 
2022-02-08 v16.14.0 
2022-01-10 v16.13.2 true
2021-12-01 v16.13.1 
2021-10-26 v16.13.0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since node publishes releases on GitHub tagged with the node version ([link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tags)), you can paginate through the GitHub API Releases endpoint ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases)).

https://api.github.com/repos/nodejs/node/releases?per_page=100&page=1

You're looking for the `tag_name` property.